# How to rebrand a nativescript app for a new country with a different language?

Tags: android, ios, git, nativescript

I have a nativescript app that I want to brand differently for each language, so I have a separate app for each language with different names and Icons and some minor differences in the codebase. But most of the codebase is the same so I would like to use git branches to be able to apply mutual changes to both codebases. How can I take care of the different names and icons and splash screens and api stuff for instance the firebase files etc?

So, I have a repository with the app for country 1 that I can easily run on my device with `tns run android --device ...` now I want to be able to make my own cli helper so that I can do `tns rebrand <country_n>` and probably have some file named `country_n` which has the configurations for the new country, e.g. path of icons and assets and git branch name etc. Can someone roughly tell me the steps that I should take? e.g. make a `git branch`, create the icons with `tns generate` change the name of the application by changing this in that file etc?

Comment: I don't think you have a built-in mechanism for branding, but you could write a before prepare CLI hook to copy right resources (images, icons, config files etc.,) to your project location.

Comment: Ok but can you help me do that? can you tell me if I want two apps that use the same codebase except for a few minor differences and also have different icon,splash screen,application name and firebase account for notifications. What should I do to what files? for example what should I do to package.json or the files in App_resources. Also if I should use different provisioning profiles. What tns commands should I run in what order. Also I edited my question in a way that would be useful for more people.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through the [{N} v6 CLI hooks](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-cli-hooks-to-nativescript-6.0) blog post. Many plugins, for instance Firebase plugin packed with hooks to copy necessary files, libraries etc., You may refer them for examples

Comment: @Manoj What about changing the name/splash screen and stuff like that? Do I need to have different provisioning profiles or not? what about the app id, app.app.com etc?

Comment: Images / Icons / Splash Screen / any file that has to be branded, the concept is the same, you are going to copy right resources for the current build. What I imagine is that, add `App_Resources` to git ignore, have a directory on my project root which will contain all branded images, icons, splash screens etc., (may be `brands/[brand-name]`). Pass an env variable which will hold brand name, the hook shall copy files from specific brand to app resources before build is prepared. I believe the same can be done just with Webpack too by configuring the copy plugin based on the brand name.

Comment: Do you need a different provisional / not - that depends on your requirement. Are you going to publish all apps under same account, then you can even use a wildcard provisional profile and certificate. Reg app id, you can modify it from hook by overriding the project info object Or you can maintain brand specific info plist and manifest file too.